# /dev/mem access denied on raspberry pi

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

I am working with my Raspberry Pi and I am writing a cgi python script that creates a webpage to control my gpio out pins. My script crashes when I try to import RPi.GPIO as GPIO. This is the error that I am getting:

```
File "./coffee.py", line 7, in &lt;module&gt;
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
```

My code works perfectly when I use sudo to run my script, but when I am running from a URL from my apache2 server it says that I do not have access to /dev/mem.  I have already tried editing visudo and that did not work. This is what my visudo file looks like:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/coffee.py *
apache2 ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/coffee.py
```

There any way that I can run my script as root from a URL call? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding www-data to the gpio user group worked fine:

```
sudo usermod -aG gpio www-data
```

You can also add www-data to the memory user group:

```
sudo usermod -aG kmem www-data
```

As mentioned, it is a bad idea, but for me it was necessary.

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache service `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the script is not executed as root. It is executed as the user that apache runs as.

Your apache process runs as a specific user, probably `www-data`. You could change the user that apache runs as. You should be able to find this in `/etc/apache2/envvars`:

```
# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

If you change that to `root` you should have access. Normally this would be a terrible security hole, but you are doing direct memory access already. Be very careful!

If you are uncomfortable with this then you need to [update your command so it is executed as root](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) (this is a good way, but it requires you understand what you are doing!). You can do this by altering the way you call it, or by wrapping the call in a script which itself changes the user, or by using [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) (this is very similar to the suEXEC approach mentioned earlier). Wrapping it in a script seems the best way to me, as that should allow your entry in `sudoers` to correctly apply the privilieges for only that command, and it doesn't require you to understand the full implications of setuid approaches.